# What are the requirements to use EGL?

Tags: opengl, nvidia, serverless, egl

I'd like to try out to redner images into files on server side without a real windowing system. Following [this article](https://developer.nvidia.com/blog/egl-eye-opengl-visualization-without-x-server/), EGL should be able to do that.

I have access to an Ubuntu server, where the following packages are installed: freeglu3, freeglut3-dev, libegl1-mesa-dev, and libglew-dev. This allows compiling, linking and running sample apps. Running `nvidia-smi` says the driver is above version 460, which is higher than the 3xx mentioned in the article.

When I try to execute the simple sample program, `eglInitialize` returns false, and `eglGetError()` is set to `EGL_NOT_INITIALIZED`.

```
EGLDisplay eglDpy = eglGetDisplay(EGL_DEFAULT_DISPLAY);
EGLint major, minor;
eglInitialize(eglDpy, &major, &minor);
```

The blog post and other SO answers say that I should link libOpenGL.so. But I'm not linking by hand, I'm using the cmake code provided in that article:

```
find_package(OpenGL REQUIRED COMPONENTS OpenGL EGL)
add_executable(your_binary_name main.c)
target_link_libraries(your_binary_name PRIVATE OpenGL::OpenGL OpenGL::EGL)
```

And idneed, looking at the generated cmake files that .so file is used:

```
your_binary_name: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libOpenGL.so
your_binary_name: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libEGL.so
your_binary_name: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLU.so
your_binary_name: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLEW.so
your_binary_name: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLX.so
```

What am I missing? I can't find any other required dependencies to set up EGL and headless rendering.

Comment: `libegl1-mesa-dev` is mesa's and not nvidia's egl implementation, you seem to have some weird mix of drivers here.

Comment: @derhass Thanks, I didn't know thos won't work together, I'll try out other packages.